How to reduce the size of Numpy data type
I am using Python to do cosine similarity.
similarity_matrix = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix)

The problem is that I am getting this error
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 44.8 GiB for an array with shape (6011226750,) and data type float64

I don't think I need float64 for this operation as 2 digits after the decimal point should be enough.
Is there a way I can change the cosine_similarity data type to a smaller one?

Even dealing with shorter type you may not solve it completely on other machines - scaling vertically will not the right way, one solution is scaling horizontally like suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/73630846/3789481, hope this help

How come it's trying to allocate a 1D array with non-square size? The output of cosine_similarity on NxM array should be NxN array. What's the shape of your input matrix?

Show the full error message

What's the tfidf_matrix dtype? shape?

You cannot change the data type of cosine_similarity, you can only change the input data.
